# Two circles covering the sides of a triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, noneuclidean-geometry

I would like to prove or find a counterexample for the following theorem:

For any $\triangle ABC, \odot P_1, \odot P_2$ such that the three lines $AB, AC, BC$ are each contained in the union of the two circles  $P_1 \cup P_2$, the entire interior of $\triangle ABC$ is contained in $P_1 \cup P_2$.

If the theorem holds in Euclidiean geometry, does it also hold in spherical geometry and/or in isotropic Lobachevski geometry (constant negative curvature)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Euclidean case: Let $X$ be an interior point of $\Delta ABC$ not covered by $P_1\cup P_2$. Then the line $\ell$ through $X$ orthogonal to the connection of the centers intersects $P_1\cup P_2$ in a (convex) line segment. Hence this line segment cannot contain *both* points where $\ell$ leaves the triangle.

Comment: Tranferring the convexity argument to the other geometries works - almost

Comment: Yes, your argument works.  And you can in fact let $\ell$ be the line defined by connecting $X$ to any point on any line of the triangle. I guess this proof also works of the spherical geometry case, but I don't see that it works for hyperbolic geometry.

Comment: In the spherical case, consider a (small) triangle with its boundary covered by two disks. Now swap the meaning of interior and exterior for the triangle ... I assume one at least to agree "interior" of circle/triangle always means "smaller part of complement", but I'm still not sure for extreme cases